# Configuring Cisco DHCP Server Multi-Homed Static Leases

Tags: cisco, dhcp, multi-homed

I have a network managed by a Cisco router with DHCP.  The network is used by some embedded software developers who use kit with fixed IP addresses.  We'd like to configure their machines to use DHCP, but that the DHCP lease should include two (ie multihomed) IP addresses, one on the subnet we have configured and one on the subnet used by the other kit.  Is there a way to configure this?

I've tried a DHCP pool like this:

```
ip dhcp pool Static1
  host 10.19.1.70 /24
  host 192.168.2.30 /24
  hardware-address 001e.0bb3.a841 ieee802
  client-identifier 0100.1e0b.b3a8.41
  client-name devpc1
  ...
```

This doesn't cause any errors, but the host gets an address from the dynamic pool instead of the statically allocated one.  I've also tried putting two addresses on the one host line:

```
  host 10.19.1.70 /24 192.168.2.30 /24
```

This causes an error when I try to load the configuration on the router.

I can't find any reference to a way to do this in the Cisco documentation or on Google.  Does anyone know if it's possible?

Answer (score 0):

DHCP client implementations never ask for more than one address on an interface - this implementation isn't possible from either the Cisco or the client system perspective.